# Select min BeginDate from duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, min, partition-by

[image]

```
select [BK_Vendedor]
       ,[NIF]
      ,[BeginDate]
      ,[EndDate]
from (
      select 
       [BK_Vendedor]
      ,[NIF]
      ,[BeginDate]
      ,[EndDate],
             count(*) over (partition by [BK_Vendedor]) as dc
      from [test_SA].[dbo].[Dim_Vendedor]
     ) as T
where dc > 1
```

This table is the result from this query that only picks duplicates values from the BK_Vendedor column from another bigger table. but in this same query i also want only the rows with the minimum BeginDate from each BK_Vendedor. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ROW_NUMBER partitioned on `BK_Vendedor` and filter on the row number being = 1. When you partition ROW_NUMBER by a field (or multiple fields!) it resets the count to 1 every time the field changes. You effectively group by the field and each group gets its own series of row numbers. We use that to get the first `BeginDate` in each group.

Note that if we wanted the *last* `BeginDate` we would reverse the ordering so the last was #1 (`ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by BK_Vendedor ORDER BY BeginDate DESC) as Ord`) and keep the WHERE clause specifying `Ord` = 1

```
with cteSampleData as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (100, 10, '2022-01-10', '2022-01-25') 
        , (100, 10, '2022-01-08', '2022-01-15') 
        , (101, 11, '2022-03-10', '2022-04-15') 
        , (102, 12, '2022-02-10', NULL) 
        , (103, 13, '2022-02-15', NULL) 
        , (103, 13, '2022-03-15', '2022-04-10') 
        , (103, 15, '2022-02-21', '2022-04-01') --EDIT: Add this row
    ) as DimVend(BK_Vendedor,NIF,BeginDate,EndDate)
) --The above is just sample data as I don't have your [test_SA].[dbo].[Dim_Vendedor]
select [BK_Vendedor]
       ,[NIF]
      ,[BeginDate]
      ,[EndDate]
from (
      select 
       [BK_Vendedor]
      ,[NIF]
      ,[BeginDate]
      ,[EndDate],
             count(*) over (partition by [BK_Vendedor]) as dc
             --Add the line below
             , ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by BK_Vendedor ORDER BY BeginDate) as Ord
      from cteSampleData
     ) as T
where dc > 1
    AND Ord = 1 --And add this line too
```

Input looks like this:

| BK_Vendedor | NIF | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-25 |
| 100 | 10 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-15 |
| 101 | 11 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-04-15 |
| 102 | 12 | 2022-02-10 | NULL |
| 103 | 13 | 2022-02-15 | NULL |
| 103 | 13 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-04-10 |

Input (in original order) with the addition of `dc` and `Ord`:

| BK_Vendedor | NIF | BeginDate | EndDate | dc | Ord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-25 | 2 | 2 |
| 100 | 10 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-15 | 2 | 1 |
| 101 | 11 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-04-15 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 12 | 2022-02-10 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 103 | 13 | 2022-02-15 | NULL | 3 | 1 |
| 103 | 13 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-04-10 | 3 | 3 |
| 103 | 15 | 2022-02-21 | 2022-04-01 | 3 | 2 |

and Output looks like this:

| BK_Vendedor | NIF | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-15 |
| 103 | 13 | 2022-02-15 | NULL |

Comment: yes the code works thanks a lot. what does the last ord = 1 means in terms of code?

Comment: @rafamaniac I added a better explanation of Ord to the answer, hopefully that makes it clearer but if not feel free to ask for more explanation. It's not just for you, you're helping future SO readers understand the answer too!

Comment: yes it does explain. thx!